# R script is not loading (kohonen library) and it is not executing in php code and same code is executing in terminal

Tags: r

I am running R script in the php code in apache webserver, in my script I am giving code for loading (`kohonen` library). whole R-script will be running through php coding as exec("Rscript script.R");

R code:

```
library("kohonen")
load(file = "som.rda")

tr<-read.csv("trainnew1.csv")
compile11<-tr
```

write.table(compile11, file = "kohonen1.txt")
and etc..........

in terminal this code is running, but while giving in php it is not executing and loading the library

for checking the library loading, i wrote simple code for addition by loading library in first line

example

```
library("kohonen")
a<-3
b<-5
c<-a+b
print(c)
```

it is not printing c in output file, because of kohonen library

same addition i tried with loading nnet library

example

```
library("nnet")
a<-3
b<-5
c<-a+b
print(c)
```

It is printing c in the output file. problem is with loading `kohonen` library
please suggest me, how to load `kohonen` libary and then how to fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, I might not have the answer you need. I just want to emphasize another thing. Please never naming a variable with c. It is an R reserved word. You can change to cc or something else. Perhaps this is also the cause of your R session not working.